# The process that has brought about the proposal and its submission?

Tags: planning, resource-planning, process, development-process

While writing a proposal, I came across a section on the template, under "PROJECT PLAN.", and I am at a loss as to the exact nature of information to provide in response to a request for" The process that has brought about the proposal and its submission.".   Is this a request to further explain what steps the organization took in preparing the proposal for submission(proposal creation strategy) or is this a request for further explanation of the rationale behind the choice of the problem this proposal is to solve(decision-making process)?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, but this sounds to me like you are being asked to explain how you came to the conclusion that your project was necessary. What discovery work have you done upfront to make sure this project will benefit the business.